# How to call back to the application from Safari browser when successfully logged in?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, mobile-safari, url-scheme

I am using webservice in my app. I have set one button login with facebook button, that drag user to safari browser and open facebook login page. Here I have not used Facebook API, all things are coming from PHP side,
now I need the user back to application which is in background when he successfully Logs in..

I have set my URL schemes as "myapp" and when user logs in successfully in PHP side I have set url to open is "myapp://" so I can get back to my app.

But here problem is when ever url "myapp://" gets called it automatically converted to "http://domainname.myapp://" so safari is not letting the user to go back to application and it stays on the bowser.

where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with "myapp://sometext" instead of just "myapp://"?

Comment: no i have not tried that...but what happened with that?

Comment: i have tried that now but its still not working..

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your application URL scheme is set correctly? I just rechecked with an app store app and my own in development (installed via xcode) and both of them can be called via safari. Do you have the project settings set correctly and implemented the necessary methods in you app delegate?

Comment: TriPhoenix probably is right! Did you set your URL scheme in your plist? An example on how to do this is here: https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare/tree/dev#facebook